# Responses from facebook graph api, objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, facebook, facebook-fql

Iam writing an iPhone application which is posting a few queries to facebook via the graph-api. My problem is that I want to handle results from different FQL queries in the same "- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result" but I havent found a way identify which query the response is for. 
Can I tag my request with an ID or something to identify it in the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`requestWithGraphPath` returns the request object, save it and then in the delegate method `request:didLoad` use it to differenciate your requests. The method `request:didLoad` is passing you the request as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Hii Jonas,

i have also to call FQL/GRaph/Checkins API in one View , so i write separated Model Object Class - then make that class to return Results to the View like writing a Protocol otherwise it s not a good idea to use multiple FB Request since requestDidLoad returns results for any FB Actions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saved the request object in a dictionary for reference...